# Entity Framework 6 and Stored Procedures with Schema names

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

So I imported a stored procedure from my database that is NOT in dbo (default) schema, to my entity model.

Name of the stored procedure is NOT dbo.MyProc; rather it is: person.MyProc (note the schema name is "person", not "dbo")

for some reason, when I try to execute the stored procedure I get an error as if EntityFramework knows nothing about MyProc being in person schema. Here's how I try to execute the stored procedure in my code:

```
using (var dbContext = new DataModel.PersonEntity())
{
    dbContext.dbOp_DeletePerson(personId);
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> The value of EntityCommand.CommandText is not valid for a
>   StoredProcedure command. The EntityCommand.CommandText value must be
>   of the form 'ContainerName.FunctionImportName'

And tracing it down a bit, here's the auto-generated line of code from Entity Framework:

> return
>   ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("dbOp_DeletePerson",
>   PersonId);

To reiterate, dbOp_DeletePerson is in "person" schema not dbo.

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the work around (I don't like it, but oh well)
http://www.dotnetbits.com/entity-framework-6-t4-templates/

1. in your Model.Context.tt look for "edmFunction.Name"
2. replace it with "edmFunction.FullName"

   [image: 1] [image: 1]

Comment: yeah tell me about it. nothing that I know of, unfortunately; we're using EF6 right now; please do update me if you do find a better alternative

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and fix it by changing function import name (and function import result name (if procedure returns data)) of one of the duplicate stored procedure.